# How to make an android application suitable for mobile and Tablets from GUI perspective

Tags: android, screen

hi guyz i know android says if u are working with gui adjust your layout positions in term of dp but in real life i faced that even dp is not benifial in my application i was using dp in layout adjustment but in the end in testing mode when we checked our application in different mobiles layout was not adjusting....and at last we handled it with code

now we have another target we want our same application compatible with Tablets...

(1) my application using Custom listview every where

how i can make compatible my app with tablet as well as mobile. 
i just need help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean using "dip" (density Independent pixels).  With that said, have you looked at using Fragments?  Fragments should help make the code more re-usable, and support tablet views and smaller screen views (phones) easier.

See here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html
And here:  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tablet-design/ (for a little tutorial)

You'll need API 3 at least, I believe.

Comment: here is the problem we done want two different builds for tablet and mobile okz here is solution what i did to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="3"
      android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

Comment: include this in ur AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html